# Can I prevent SMS from showing on the Lock Screen in iOS 4?

Tags: iphone, ios, sms

I have some private SMS messages I want to hide. The problem is that they are displaying on main screen even when it's locked. So it was useless using password because it's displayed even with the lock.

How can I make SMS messages hidden on locked screen?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to Settings > Messages. There's an option "Show Preview" there. If you toggle this to off, it will stop showing SMS previews on the lock screen. This will also disable the alert popup when a new SMS arrives and the phone is not locked.

Comment: This is outdated as of iOS 5.0 and above. See [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45642/218) for the updated version.

Comment: This is still relevant to iOS 5.0, if you want to get notifications of text messages on the lock screen but you don't want the content of the SMS to be visible.

Answer (score 3):

As of the latest OS (5.0 and 5.1), you use the following method:

**To turn off Message preview:**

1. Launch the **Settings** app.
2. Navigate to **Notifications > Messages**.
3. Scroll down to **Show Preview** and set it to **Off**.

Now, instead of showing the actual message on the lock screen and in notifications, it will only tell you that you received a message and by whom you received it.

Answer (score 1):

Go into settings->notifications->messages and turn off the badges option.

Comment: You can also turn off 'View in Lock Screen' to off from the same location.

Answer (score 0):

If you're jailbroken, [iBlacklist](http://www.iblacklist.com.br/) is an excellent app. You can block SMS and calls from your phone completely. The app intercepts them, and can save the logs. It is password-protected, so there's an extra layer of security as well.

Even if you don't want to blacklist anyone, you can still set it so that you don't get a popup at all when new SMS messages arrive. Your messages will go to your regular inbox, and you'll still hear the alert, but no popup.

Free trial, costs $12 to buy.

I have also heard about [MCleaner](http://www.mcleaner.com/). Never used that one though.

Comment: $12 for that. Seems a bit expensive for the features...

Comment: Yeah. I agree. There are alternative methods for obtaining said software too. Not that I condone or partake, but the pirates sail the jailbroken seas as well.